# JS function doesn't change box color

Tags: javascript, html, css

JS just refuses to do anything - doesn't show console.log, doesn't show any errors, doesn't do anything.

JS just doesn't give any signs of life really - I tried making `document.getelementbyid(box1)` and ("#box") and ("box") because of people on the internet use all these and it works.

Tried to make events embedded in HTML to call the function, tried to call the function on window.onload, etc.

Tried changing text and color and size and margins - nothing works. And there is sometimes a null error - meaning that JS can't get the style value for some reason.

```js
var box = document.getElementById("#box1");

function changeColor() {
  var box = document.getElementById("#box1");
  box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```css
#box1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #B9E257;
}

#box2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #69ADE1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="N.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="box1">1</div>

  <div id="box2">2</div>

  <button onclick="changeColor()">Go!</button>

  <script src="N.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Why on earth would it not work?

Comment: Try removing the # from id just (box1)

Comment: ```var box = document.getElementById("box1");```. getElementById does not require an octothorpe since it already knows it's looking for the ID.

Comment: well i saw it in some example on the web and that was actually JQuery not vanilla JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Document method getElementById() returns an Element object
>   representing the element whose id property matches the specified
>   string. Since element IDs are required to be unique if specified,
>   they're a useful way to get access to a specific element quickly.

For more info visit the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

The ID is case-sensitive string which is unique within the document;

Please check the running example below:

```js
function changeColor() {
    var box = document.getElementById("box1");
    console.log(box);
    box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```css
#box1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #B9E257;
}

#box2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #69ADE1;
}
```

```html
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="N.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

    <div id="box1">1</div>

    <div id="box2">2</div>

    <button onclick="changeColor()">Go!</button>

    <script src="N.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: oh thank you all people for your help, thanks a lot! Its funny how i got the understanding of DOM and all the theory part, but as soon as i start coding i get stuck with such simple thing for like hours, thats so frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Your JS throwing error just because you are using `#` in `document.getElementById` which is not allowed. You need to define `#` for `ID` in jQuery not in JS.

Here is the updated code. Just only removed `#` from `document.getElementById` nothing else I have done in it.

```js
function changeColor() {
    var box = document.getElementById("#box1");
    box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```css
#box1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #B9E257;
}

#box2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #69ADE1;
}
```

```html
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="N.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

    <div id="box1">1</div>

    <div id="box2">2</div>

    <button onclick="changeColor()">Go!</button>

    <script src="N.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: cant believe thats it - tried this exact variant for like 2 times and now it simply works, thank you Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

If you really like that #, then instead of
var box = document.getElementById("#box1");
do

```
var box = document.querySelector("#box1");
```